# Galaxy Nexus - AOSP certificate

Tags: android, certificate, android-source, sign

I'm developing a system app in android. However, I will need system certificates for that purpose. I wanted to know, if I sign my app with AOSP system certificate, will it work on Nexus devices?

I know manufacturers like samsung and HTC have their own system certificates, so I cannot run my system app on their devices. Just want to know, will my app work on Nexus devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to sign your app to make it a system app on Nexus devices. The key used by Google is private. It would be a big security issue allowing "random developers" to create system apps.

But there are some "androids" using the android debug key as system signature (e.g. most custom roms (newer cm versions won't work because they have other security mechanisms implemented to avoid misuse of system apps) or a lot of "low-budget" china manufacturers)